# ggplot2 graphing two subsets

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphing

I have a CSV data set that looks like this:

```
GPU_Config,Job_Num,Stack_Num,Seconds
02_13,2,16double,1106
02_13,4,16double,906.25
02_13,6,16double,914.75
02_13,8,16double,982.5
02_13,10,16double,1013.25
02_13,12,16double,1067.5
02_13,16,16double,1026.25
0_1_2_3,4,16double,959.75
0_1_2_3,8,16double,847.5
0_1_2_3,12,16double,976.5
0_1_2_3,16,16double,972.75
```

I want to graph two `geom_smooth()`, each using a separate type of `GPU_Config`, `02_13` and `0_1_2_3`. I can use `R`'s subset method within the `ggplot()` parameters like this:

```
ggplot(subset(test, GPU_Config %in% c("02_13", "0_1_2_3")), aes(y = Seconds, x = Job_Num, color = GPU_Config)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point()
```

However, this results in a graph looking like this:

[image: Test Graph]

I wish to separate the two smoothers, to be able to manipulate each individually for each data subset (`gpu type`). However, something like this below, does not work:

```
ggplot(test, aes(y = Seconds, x = Job_Num)) + geom_smooth(subset(test, GPU_Config %in% c("02_13"))) + geom_smooth(subset(test, GPU_Config %in% c("0_1_2_3"))) + geom_point()
```

and results in this error:

```
Error: Mapping must be created by `aes()` or `aes_()`
```

Could someone please help with getting this done? Note I am not an R expert by any means.

Comment: If you plot `ggplot(test[8:11, ], aes(y = Seconds, x = Job_Num)) + geom_smooth()`, you'll see that ggplot can't actually get a geom_smooth() for your the second part of your data.

Comment: Is this data just, not compatible with the default smoothing method?

Comment: You often need to specifically write out the `data` argument within geoms as `data` is not the first argument like it is in `ggplot`.  Try `geom_smooth(data  = subset(...etc...))`.  The error is because the first argument in `geom_smooth` is `mapping`, but you give a dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you also stratify the `fill` colour:

```
ggplot(subset(test, GPU_Config %in% c("02_13", "0_1_2_3"))) +
    aes(y = Seconds, x = Job_Num, color = GPU_Config, fill = GPU_Config) +
    geom_smooth() +
    geom_point()
```

However, in all cases your `02_13` config runs into problems with local fitting — your code issues appropriate warnings, even in the original version. To fix this, a different smoothing method is required, e.g.:

```
ggplot(subset(test, GPU_Config %in% c("02_13", "0_1_2_3"))) +
    aes(y = Seconds, x = Job_Num, color = GPU_Config, fill = GPU_Config) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm) +
    geom_point()
```

This will separate the confidence intervals by `GPU_Config`.

Comment: When I graph what you wrote I get the same graph as I did, with just a different color fill. (All light blue instead of all gray). Would you mind telling me what exactly is wrong with my code (warnings and all that/why a different smoothing method)?

Comment: Also in any case, is there still  a way for me to write this code so I can individually edit smoothing for each GPU type? (Again not R expert by any means)

Comment: @antong Like I said, you cannot use LOESS smoothing with your data — that’s what the warnings tell you, and that’s why the smoothed confidence interval is missing for your `02_13` config. A different smoothing method (e.g. `method = lm`) makes this error go away, but obviously result in a fundamentally different plot.

Comment: @antong You shouldn’t use different smoothing methods for subsets of data in the same plot, that’s misleading (and consequently ggplot2 has no way of doing this easily).

Comment: No of course, I wouldnt use 2 different smoothing methods, I just wished to separate the two GPU configurations in the sense that their fills could have different colors, so one can differentiate between the two, but still using the same smoothing method for each config. So you're saying that if I try and use a different smoothing method (for all data), the two configs will "separate" in their fills/the errors will go away?

Comment: @antong Yes, that’s what my answer is trying to say. I hope my edit is making this clearer.

Comment: Ok, understood. Thank you. I shall test that out soon and hopefully it shall all be resolved :)